# Images on center in the division

Tags: html, css, image, center

I have divisions(`same width and height`) with image(`different width and height`). I try to center on that image inside the division. so use

```
{ text-align: center}
```

here the image comes center but top value is not changed.

Here the eg image what i exactly need.

[image]

Here the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Arav8/1/) what i tried. I am waiting for your advice. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell` to align the inner images to middle of the div.

But in this case you cant give `margin` because `table-cell` forces `div` to act as a `td` and technically you cant give margin to table `td`.

So I have added border to div with white color.

**CSS**

```
.background-image{
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #C8BFE7;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:white 5px solid
}
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Arav8/3/)**

**------------------------------OR----------------------------------------**

You can add an outer div to each div and specify margin to outer div.

**CSS**

```
.outer{margin: 0 0 10px 10px; display:inline-block}
.background-image{
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #C8BFE7;    
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
​
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Arav8/7/)**